# How to center roman numerals above list items

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a list where the roman numeral appears directly above the text, ie, to look like this:

```
                                         I.
                                    Text Text Text
```

This is the code I tried, but I think the align is aligning the entire list instead of just the roman numerals.

```
<ol type="I">
<li>To be respected for our occupational and educational choices</li>
<br>
<li>To meet occupational standards set by employers and to be proficient in workplace basics</li>
<br>
<li>To receive a world class education</li>
<br>
<li>To earn credentials and degrees which qualify us for further education and work</li>
<br>
<li>To receive guidance that fits our interests and aptitudes</li>
<br>
<li>To work in the occupations for which we have trained</li>
<br>
<li>To study in safe and stimulating schools</li>
<br>
<li>To serve our communities</li>
<br>
<li>To learn from competent instructors committed to the success of their students</li>
<br>
<li>To meet face0to-face with business,industry, and organized Labor</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Just a little question, why do you have `br`s between `li`s?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [CSS2 counters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Counters).

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/itay1989/chBxm/3/)

```
ol {
    counter-reset: my-counter;
    list-style-type: none;
}

ol li {
    text-align: center;
}

ol li:before {
    content: counter(my-counter, upper-roman) ".";
    counter-increment: my-counter;
    display: block;
}
```

For further reading: [Numbering in style](http://css-tricks.com/numbering-in-style/)

---

Another alternative is to create a line break at the beginning of each list item. This has some browser support issues (works only on FF but maybe with some extra work to it you'll be able to fix this).

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/itay1989/chBxm/2/)

```
ol li:before {
     content :"\A"; 
     white-space: pre; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work I think ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wn6YT/))

CSS:

```
li {
    text-align: center;
}
```

HTML:

```
<ol type="I">
<li><br>To be respected for our occupational and educational choices</li>
<br>
<li><br>To meet occupational standards set by employers and to be proficient in workplace basics</li>
<br>
<li><br>To receive a world class education</li>
<br>
<li><br>To earn credentials and degrees which qualify us for further education and work</li>
<br>
<li><br>To receive guidance that fits our interests and aptitudes</li>
<br>
<li><br>To work in the occupations for which we have trained</li>
<br>
<li><br>To study in safe and stimulating schools</li>
<br>
<li><br>To serve our communities</li>
<br>
<li><br>To learn from competent instructors committed to the success of their students</li>
<br>
<li><br>To meet face0to-face with business,industry, and organized Labor</li>
</ol>
```

If you want it specific to this list, create a class for the `li` in CSS. Also, I left your original breaks in for the spacing, but I would remove those and use a pad or margin in the CSS.